# Getting the final redirected URL

Tags: python, urllib, redirect, python-3.4

My code is as follows:

```
url_orig ='http://www.has-sante.fr/portail/jcms/c_676945/fr/prialt-ct-5245'
u = urllib.request.urlopen(url_orig)
print (u.geturl())
```

Basically when the URL gets redirected twice. The output should be:

```
http://www.has-sante.fr/portail/upload/docs/application/pdf/2008-07/ct-5245_prialt_.pdf
```

But the output that I'm getting is the first redirect:

```
http://www.has-sante.fr/portail/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_676945
```

How do I get the required final URL? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: loop until the response isn't a redirect?

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry I'm new to this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might be a bit overkill for what you want, but it is an alternative to using regular expressions. This answer uses the Selenium web automator [Python APIs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) to follow the redirects. It will also open up the pdf file in a browser window. The code below requires that you are using Firefox, but you can also use other browsers by replacing the name with the one you want to use i.e. webdriver.Chrome(), webdriver.Ie().

To install selenium: `pip install selenium`

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
link = 'http://www.has-sante.fr/portail/jcms/c_676945/fr/prialt-ct-5245'

driver.get(link)
print(driver.current_url)
```

It is also possible to run the browser in the background so no window pops up. The added benefit to this solution is that if they change the way the re-direction works you will not need to update the regular expressions in your code.

Comment: Yes I had to use this method instead of urllib. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This will work, they are redirecting using javascript or the  html tag, and as such looking for the "Location" header wont work. This is not an elegant solution, but it works.

```
import urllib.request
url ='http://www.has-sante.fr/portail/jcms/c_676945/fr/prialt-ct-5245'

req = str(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
url = req.split("URL=\\'")[1].split("\\'\">'")[0].strip("../")

print("http://www.has-sante.fr/portail/" + url)
```